# In TYPO3, with extbase and fluid, what is the definition of a "widget"

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

What is a "widget" in TYPO3?

I'm having some challenges creating an extension, and I'm seeing a lot of references to "widgets" doing this and that.

I don't know if "widget" is synonymous with "extension". I don't know if it would be a special kind of extension, or if an extension may contain several widgets.

I've probably spent 20-30 hours of the last week reading documentation, and I am ever so close to my goals. Please, kind sirs and madams, pray tell what exactly is a widget (in TYPO3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at Flow documentation [definition of Widgets](http://flowframework.readthedocs.org/en/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/Templating.html#widgets). The main conclusions are:

1. Widget - is a **special ViewHelper**, which is used in Fluid templates. So, your extension may contain as many widgets, as you want.
2. Widget must contain an own Controller. So, this makes is different from a ususal ViewHelper, since ViewHelpers are usually stateless and they don't take part in MVC process. But Widgets can contain a state and they are part of MVC, so can be treated as **special plugins**.
3. Widgets are bound to caller context. It means, that if Controller of your Widget looks for `$this->settings`, then settings will be read from an extension, that uses a Widget (this was my experience in TYPO3 6.2).

So, as you see - Widget is a ViewHelper and Plugin at same time. A good example of Widget is [f:widget.paginate](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Widget/PaginateViewHelper.html) - it can be used in Fluid template of any extension, and at same time it fully interacts with MVC stack.

Comment: new link:  https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/10.4/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Widget/Paginate.html 
And beware, it is deprecated sind TYPO3 10.4.